# Azure: no IP Address for ACI

Tags: ip-address, azure-container-instances

I'm into a mystery regarding the creation of a container instance. Two I have running. Both running .NET 5.0.1 and pretty default stuff.
Working for 3 months. Suddenly, on of them gets no IP address anymore. After having look in all logs available, AI, Console Log image creation, compilation, repository recreated
the image remains stuck on status: 'Creating'.

I use a powershell script to recreate the instance, no 'funny things' have changed here.

When I deploy locally on Docker, it works. I get connectivity.

NO IP address is given by Azure.
Any suggestions? The default stuff, I have done (logs as explained)...
[image]

Comment: I think it's a normal thing. When the container does not finish creating, it will not get the IP address. So you need to find out why does the container stuck in the creating state.

Comment: oh I guess I did not figure that. ... Seriously?

Comment: If don't know the reason that your instance stuck in the creating state. You need to find it out. If not, maybe it will be always in the creating state

Comment: I already see it! I don't see any useful details to figure out what is the reason. I only see it's in the creating state.

Answer (score 0):

Suddenly today, I get a new IP. So probably, the answer would be 'pay-as-you-go' does not guarantee connectivity for 99.9%.
MS Azure, you should improve this! Give at least a message.